# Separate the nested array and get the value only php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried lot unable to get values from the nested array

here is the array:

```
$array = Array (
    Array (20, 21, 22),
    Array (20, 21, 23),
    Array (20, 22, 23),
    Array (21, 22, 23)
);
```

output should look like

```
 20 21 22
 20 21 23
 20 22 23
 21 22 23
```

please help

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I reformatted your array to be valid php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    [20, 21, 22],
    [20, 21, 22],
    [20, 21, 22],
    [20, 21, 22]
];

foreach ($arr as $row) {
  echo implode(' ', $row) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: maybe you should note that the short array syntax was introduced with PHP 5.4 (last year?) which may not be present on all servers, especially not on shared hosting server

Answer (score 2):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
$array; // this is your 2d array
foreach ($array as $k) {
    $out = "";
    foreach ($k as $n) {
        $out .= $n." ";
    }
    print_r($out."\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will cycle through each of the top level elements of the array and output row elements for each of the outer array elements.

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($array as $row): ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo implode("</td><td>", $row) ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: it's not the most readable code, and there are no explanations.

Comment: @rjmunro I though the code was very readable within a view context as opposed to a data manipulation context, since flattening out an array to a string is a view operation. Anyway added an explanation and indention.

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursion($arr){
   foreach($arr as $key => $val){
       if (is_array($val)){
           recursion($val);
       } else {
           print($val." ");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Advice: have a look at `array_walk_recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to loop through the outer array with `foreach` and implode the inner arrays:

```
$array = Array (
    Array (20, 21, 22),
    Array (20, 21, 23),
    Array (20, 22, 23),
    Array (21, 22, 23)
);

foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo implode(" ", $row) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in php ... not `+`, this will throw a Fatal error.

Comment: @Orangepill whoops, fixed now.